Basis over $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with complex structure
Let $V$ be a 2n-dimensional real vector space $V$. Then, every endomorphism $J:V \to V$ with $J^2 = -id_V$ indces a complex structure on $V$ by
$$(a+ib) \cdot v := a \cdot v + b \cdot J(v).$$
we denote this complex vector space by $(V,J)$.
I want to find a basis in $(V,J)$.  I think that if $\{e_1, \ldots e_n\}$ are linearly independent vectors in $V$, then $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n, J(e_1),\ldots, J(e_n)\}$ form a basis in $V$. If I prove this, then $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ form a basis in $(V,J)$.
My idea was to use induction. If $e_1 \ne 0$ in $V$, then, if $a e_1 + b J(e_1) = 0 \implies J(ae_1 + bJ(e_1))=aJ(e_1)-be_1 = J(0) = 0$, so $abJ(e_1)-b^2e_1 = 0 \implies a(-ae_1)-b^2e_1 = 0 \implies -(a^2+b^2)e_1 = 0 \implies a^2+b^2 = 0 \implies a = b = 0.$ So, $\{e_1, J(e_1)\}$ are linearly independent.
Now, suppose that $\{e_1, \ldots, e_{k-1}, J(e_1), \ldots, J(e_{k-1})\}$ are linearly independent. We need to prove that $\{e_1, \ldots, e_{k}, J(e_1), \ldots, J(e_{k})\}$ are also linearly independent. If we choose $e_k \notin \operatorname{span}(e_1,\ldots,e_{k-1},J(e_1),\ldots,J(e_{k-1}))$, then $\{e_1,\ldots,e_k,J(e_1),\ldots,J(e_{k-1})\}$ are linearly independent.
Now, we need to prove that if $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i e_i + \sum_{i=1}^k b_iJ(e_i) = 0$, with $a_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}$ then $a_i = b_i = 0$, but here I'm stuck.
Edit: I think my question was wrong. I want to show that there exists a basis for $V$ such that it is of the form $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n,J(e_1),\ldots,J(e_n)\}$. If we prove by induction that we can find $2n$ such linearly independent vectors, then they form a basis for $V$

You do linear algebra over C. That's it. No surprises.

@Pedro I understand but I have no idea how can I continue...

You accepted a nonsensical chatbot-generated answer.  What you are trying to prove is false.  Here's a counterexample.  Let $V = \mathbb{C}^2$, regarded as a 4-dimensional real vector space by forgetting the complex structure.  Of course, we still have that complex structure $J$, and it multiplies vectors by $i$.  Let $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(i,0)$.  These are linearly independent over the reals, but ${e_1,e_2,J(e_1),J(e_2)}$ don't span $V$.

@AndyPutman why they don't span $V$. I din't understand...

What does $d_V$ mean?

@MathLearner: Just write it out: ${e_1,e_2,J(e_1),J(e_2)} = {(1,0),(i,0),J(1,0),J(i,0)} = {(1,0),(i,0),(i,0),(i^2,0)} =  {(1,0),(i,0),(i,0),(-1,0)}$.

It is interesting. And just need some linear algebra.
Note that $U=\langle e,Je\rangle$ is a two dimensional subspace with $JU=U$. If $Je=\lambda e$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, then $J^2e=\lambda^2 e\neq -1 e$. So $\dim \langle e, Je\rangle=2$, with $J(e, Je)=(Je,-e)$.
Assume we have $e_1,\ldots, e_k,Je_1,\ldots, Je_k$ linearly independent, with $W=\langle e_1,\ldots, e_k,Je_1,\ldots, Je_k\rangle$ satisfying $JW=W$.
If $W\neq V$, then we can find $0\neq e\in V\setminus W$.
Let $U=\langle e,Je\rangle$. Assume $0\neq v= a e+bJe\in U\cap W$.
Then $Jv=-b e+a Je\in U\cap W$. Note that
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a&b\\
-b&a
\end{vmatrix}=a^2+b^2\neq 0.$$
Then we have $e\in U\cap W$, a contradiction. Hence $U\cap W=0$.
Then with $e_{k+1}=e$, we can extend the linearly independent set to
$$e_1,\ldots, e_{k+1},Je_1,\ldots, Je_{k+1}.$$
